# Python Unable to get the required text using pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to get the text between Job POS and working role. I need to get it in one variable .

```
import re
req_id_num = """Job POS: -PLEASE MAKE SURE YOU ARE GOOD.

-LOOKING FOR CONTRACTOR WHO IS STRONG IN LIFTING.

-LOOKING FOR SOMEONE WHO IS PROFICIENT IN AT THE EXECUTIVE LEVEL.

-Looking for more of a financial background than accounting background, working role"""

 Req_Job_description = re.search(r'Job POS: -(.*?) working role',
 req_id_num).group(0)

 if Req_Job_description:    
     print "search -->searchObj.group():",Req_Job_description
 else:    print "Nothing found!!"
```

I get the following error when running this

```
Req_Job_description = re.search(r'Job POS: -(.*?) working role', req_id_num).group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not avoid regular expressions (which you should, most of the time) and use `slicing` instead?

```
description = text[len("Job POS: "):-len(" working role")]
```

This slices off the prefix and suffix according to their length.

Answer (score 0):

This fails because your search text contains newlines. The dot character (by default) matches anything *except* newlines. You need to include the `re.DOTALL` flag to change this behavior. A simplified example:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile("INTRO: (.*?) TRAILER")
>>> m = pat.search("INTRO: this is data TRAILER")
>>> m.group(1)
'this is data'
>>> m = pat.search("INTRO: this \nis\n data TRAILER")
>>> m
>>> # m is None -- no Match object was returned.
```

Try again with the `DOTALL` flag:

```
>>> pat = re.compile("INTRO: (.*?) TRAILER", re.DOTALL)
>>> m = pat.search("INTRO: this \nis\n data TRAILER")
>>> m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x106b87738>
>>> m.group(1)
'this \nis\n data'
```